# R regex: split a string by combination of \\n [A-z] & [:punct:]

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a dataframe with character strings that look like this:

```
bla bla.\n14:39:51 info: pyku bla .\n14:39:51 info: \n14:39:51 info: \n14:39:57 Sam: <span>pyk pyk</span>\n14:43:15 on and on \n14:43:59 you get an idea
```

I want to split lines separated by `\n(number):(number):(number)` sequence into different rows. I tried

```
stringr::separate_rows(df3$Transcript[1], Transcript , sep = "\\n")
```

and its different combinations with `[A-z]` and `[:punct:]` to no avail. What would be the most straight forward way of doing it?

Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear: `strsplit(s, "\n")` does not work for you, does it? If not use `strsplit(s, "\\R+(?=\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})", perl=TRUE)`

Comment: `\\n(?=\\d+:\\d+:\\d+)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I wish it did!

Comment: @AvinashRaj: thank you, that worked brilliantly! if you post it as the answer, I'll happilly accept it, thanks!

Comment: @KasiaKulma Wiktor will write more beautiful answer than me :-)

Comment: @KasiaKulma You do not need to use `stringr` for that, you may use a base R `strsplit`, see my top comment. Besides, PCRE regex contains a very nice `\R` construct to match *any* line breaks. *stringr* is based on ICU regex library and it has no `\R` support. Does `strsplit(s, "\\R+(?=\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})", perl=TRUE)` work for you, too?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: your solution produces exactly the same answer as AvinashRaj's, I'm not sure what's the advantage..?

Comment: Ok, let me answer to explain my approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to split the strings with a line break that is followed with a timestamp. You may use a base R `strsplit` function with a PCRE regex based on a positive lookahead:

```
strsplit(s, "\\R+(?=\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})", perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1FtLvu/1)

**Pattern details**

- `\R+` - 1 or more line break sequences (either `\n` or `\r` or `\r\n`)
- `(?=\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})` - followed with 2 digits, `:`,  2 digits, `:` and again 2 digits. Since `(?=...)` is a positive lookahead (a zero-width assertion that does not put the matched chars into the match value) the text matched with it is not removed from the results.

[R demo](https://ideone.com/HIFgjK):

```
s <- "bla bla.\n14:39:51 info: pyku bla .\n14:39:51 info: \n14:39:51 info: \n14:39:57 Sam: <span>pyk pyk</span>\n14:43:15 on and on \n14:43:59 you get an idea"
strsplit(s, "\\R+(?=\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})", perl=TRUE)
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "bla bla."                           "14:39:51 info: pyku bla ."         
[3] "14:39:51 info: "                    "14:39:51 info: "                   
[5] "14:39:57 Sam: <span>pyk pyk</span>" "14:43:15 on and on "               
[7] "14:43:59 you get an idea"
```